# Rolling timedelta-temporal window with xarray

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

Pandas offers a rolling mean with a *fixed temporal window size*, i.e. `df.rolling('365D')`. I'd like to achieve the same effect with `xarray`, but it is currently limited to an integer (i.e. `da.rolling(time=30, min_periods=1)`. This would've suffice, had my data been in fixed intervals. Unfortunately it is not...

As an alternative, I've so far have gone in a loop over the values in the `time` dimension, and used `xarray`'s `da.sel(time=slice(t-pd.Timedelta(365, 'D'), t).mean()` to create this rolling window. This approach is, for obvious reasons, quite slow (and not vectorized).

Are there any vectorized solutions to this within `xarray`?

Minimal example to recreate such a dataset:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

arr = np.random.random((180, 3, 3))
missing = np.random.choice([0, 1], 180*3*3).reshape(180, 3, 3).astype(bool)
arr[missing] = np.nan
dates = np.datetime64("2022-01-01") + np.random.choice(365, size=180)
dates.sort()
ds = xr.Dataset(dict(values=(["time", "y", "x"], arr)), coords=dict(time=dates, y=[0, 1, 2], x=[0, 1, 2]))
```

And the current approach is e.g.

```py
TMAX = np.timedelta64(60, 'D')
last_timestamp = ds.time.isel(time=-1).values
for t in ds.time.values:  # Interested in vectorizing this loop
    if last_timestamp - t < TMAX:
        break
    print(t,
          # Number of samples in the given time range
          ds["values"].sel(time=slice(t, t+TMAX)).shape[0], "\n",
          # temporally-fixed moving average of varying window size
          ds["values"].sel(time=slice(t, t+TMAX)).mean(dim="time").values)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your data array `da` please?

Comment: Hey @Corralien! My bad, I added such an example.